# Pycharm does not recognize Django no matter how many times I install it

Tags: django, terminal, pip, pycharm, virtual-environment

I'm new to programming, so please bear with me, I have a hard time understanding what my problem even is many times, let alone explain it.

I am attempting to edit a Django app in Pycharm. I have managed to set up a virtual environment, then installed Django in that environment using pip in the terminal, but Pycharm still seems to treat references to Django like they're errors.

[Here's what it looks like in Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U3wU.png)

This ends up giving me issues where my virtual environment won't run. I feel like I'm very close to finally getting this to work, but something is wrong and I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

I tried looking up Django plugins to install through Pycharm's Marketplace section, and none existed. I then installed Django into my virtual environment using the terminal and pip, and it still doesn't recognize Django. I get error messages whenever I try to run my Django App in the virtual environment, I get error messages.

Comment: You need to configure Python interpreter within PyCharm to use one where Django is installed - There is a project setting called Python Interpreter

Comment: There is no interpreter in the same directory as Django. And when I try to add a Python Interpreter to the directory where Django is installed, it says "Environment location directory is not empty", and won't allow me to add the interpreter.

Comment: The Python interpreter is in the directory of your virtual environment. It is called `bin/python` on UNIX and `bin/python.exe` on Windows.